# Backbone.js model attribute being returned undefined but debugging shows it set in console

Tags: jquery, symfony1, backbone.js

I've been messing with backbone for a couple days now and coming up I guess with a misunderstanding in the order that backbone finally sets an attribute within a model. I have the following code:

Inside a model.js file -

```
SampleModel: Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: 'a url',
  defaults: {
    attrA: 'value',
  },
  initialize: function() {
    // init of model relationships
  },
  parse: function(response) {
    this.set({attrA: response.attrAUpdateValue});
  },
});
```

Inside a view.js file -

```
SampleView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    model = new SampleModel();
    model.fetch();

    console.log(model.get('attrA')); // Returns 'value' from default.
    console.log(model.attributes); // Inspect the attributes for the model and see that attrA does not have updated value.
  },
});
```

How do I ensure that 'attrA' has a value when working in the view outside of binding the model on change in order to work with attrA?  Or, is that the way to think of it in the realm of backbone?  Do something with a model once an attribute has changed?

Thanks in advance for help.

**UPDATE**: My bad I've updated the comments accordingly, prior I had said that the first console log would contain an undefined value.  It should have stated that the value is that of the default value and not the expected updated value that should have been set during the parse action.

Comment: I just setup a jsfiddle and I was getting the correct values.  How are you initializing your SampleView?

Comment: I have a symfony php view file where I instantiate SampleView, so basically at the the top:

`<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    aView = new SampleView({el: $('selector') });
  });
</script>`.


All necessary js files, models, views, collections etc get autoloaded through symfony configuration files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The point is, Backbone `fetch` is async. To ensure `attrA` has value use `success`callback:

```
SampleView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    model = new SampleModel();
    model.fetch({success: function(){
        console.log(model.get('attrA')); // Returns new value
    });
  },
});
```

Comment: Another good way to debug is to log the 'all':
model.on 'all', function(name) {console.log(name)}